# Deleting all keys in a shelve file through terminal/command line

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line

I'm trying to delete all items in a shelve file by allowing the user to type "clear" in terminal.

Based on several threads I've read on this website, shelve files generally behave like dictionaries, so the `.clear` method and several other approaches should work, and in fact do when I test them out in the interactive shell. But I can't get them to work in my program.

Here's my latest attempt (which worked in the shell):

```
elif len(sys.argv) == 3 and sys.argv[1].lower() == 'clear':
    for key in mcbShelf:
        del mcbShelf[key]
```

Just using `del` on mcbShelf also did not work.

My program also has a "list" feature that lists all of the keys stored in the shell.

```
elif len(sys.argv) == 2:
    #list keywords
    if sys.argv[1].lower() == 'list':
        pyperclip.copy(str(list(mcbShelf.keys())))
```

When I try `python3.5 mcb4.pyw clear` in Terminal, then run `python3.5 mcb4.pyw list`, I believe an empty list should be copied to the clipboard. But the list has objects in it.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `len(sys.argv) == 3` should be 2.

Comment: @friendlyman23 can you verify that this answer works and accept it if it does? He's been kind enough to offer a solution, you should let us know whether it works so others don't waste their time on it.

Comment: Hi, no, still getting the same problem after changing changing it to `len(sys.argv) == 2`. Although it SHOULD be 2, not 3, as well.

Comment: Did you check by printing something that the elif section is actually run ?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I added this, but got nothing:
    `elif len(sys.argv) == 2 and sys.argv[1].lower() == 'clear':`
        `mcbShelf.clear()`
        `print('Hello')`
Would this print directly to terminal?

Comment: Yes, if the `print` has the same indention as the mcbShelf.clear(), it prints directly to the terminal after the `clear`'s execution. If there is no output, it means that the elif part is not executed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, will look into this.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like chapter 8 of automate the boring stuff :) Well, didn't like the coding style of that one. Here is my approach, **including** delete one, and delete all commands.

```
import shelve
import pyperclip
import sys

mcbShelf = shelve.open('mcb')
command = sys.argv[1].lower()

if command == 'save':
    mcbShelf[sys.argv[2]] = pyperclip.paste()
elif command == 'list':
    pyperclip.copy(", ".join(mcbShelf.keys()))
elif command == 'delete':
    del mcbShelf[sys.argv[2]]
elif command == 'delete_all':
    mcbShelf.clear()
else:
    pyperclip.copy(mcbShelf[sys.argv[1]])

mcbShelf.close()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'm reviewing your post because it's your first. Posts like yours can be valuable not only to the person that asked the question but to the many people who look for answers later. With this in mind, I wonder if you would consider adding commentary that shows how the rest of your answer relates to the original question? Again, glad you're here.

Answer (score 1):

I found 2 ways to deal with this. One is to create a function to delete the files the other is to pull a condition flag based on a argument and name it the same file. This is verified working code.

```
import shelve
import pyperclip
import sys
import os

mcbShelf = shelve.open('mcb')
command = sys.argv[1].lower()

def remove_files():
    mcbShelf.close()
    os.remove('mcb.dat')
    os.remove('mcb.bak')
    os.remove('mcb.dir')


if command == 'save':
    mcbShelf[sys.argv[2]] = pyperclip.paste()
elif command == 'list':
    pyperclip.copy(", ".join(mcbShelf.keys()))
elif command == 'del':
    mcbShelf.close() 
    # call the flag 'n' Always create a new, empty database
    mcbShelf = shelve.open('mcb', flag= 'n')
    # or delete the files
    remove_files()
else:
    pyperclip.copy(mcbShelf[sys.argv[1]])

mcbShelf.close()
```